# How to put a REST Api react native + django application on google play?

Tags: django, react-native, rest

I am creating a REST APi mobile application with native React and Django.
I would like to know if it is possible to create an "apk" with a rest api application. Knowing that I am making http requests from react to django. I don't understand or I don't know if it's possible? Is it possible to host a rest api application? If so how do we do with react native and django?

Thanks you !

Answer (score -1):

It's exactly the same thing as for React web: Fetch the data from your URL using the same query system and use it like you would in web-dev.